# RecyclerView childView always with the same id

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

**MY PROBLEM** 
All views inside my RecyclerView, I am talking about elements(TextView and ImageView ....) are displayed well, normal but when i want to list all items inside the recyclerView with this:

```
for(int i=0;i<recyclerView.getChildCount();i++){
    ids=ids+"-"+recyclerView.getChildAt(i).getId();
}
```

when i display ids always show me the same id which is the RelativeLayout id and it supose to display the id of the elements inside the RecyclerView as the TextView, ImageView and more

**MY RESEARCH**

i was following a video from slidenerd of

> RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener

and for him is working fine i dont know why for my is not working i was reading a lot about my problem to find the exact problem because:

1. First thing i did change the ids names for all my layouts to be different
2. Move the position of my code
3. Confirm that the data sent by MotionEvent e.getX() and y.getY() was correct and even thought i change the methods for getRaw
4. Read about RecyclerView class and find that there is not issue in this method findChildVIewUnder because all things that do are mathematicals
5. Read the id number of each important resource in R file an then convert it to dec to compare the prompt
6. I am close to the frustation 
   **MY CODE**

> teacher_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/problem"
android:layout_width="328dp"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/borders">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/teacher_item_picture"
    style="@style/TeacherItemImage" />

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/teacher_item_ratingbar"
    style="@style/TeacherItemRatingBar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/teacher_item_name"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="16.5dp"
    style="@style/TeacherItemName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/teacher_item_courses"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    style="@style/TeacherItemCourses" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/teacher_item_faculties"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    style="@style/TeacherItemFaculties" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> recyclerview.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/generic_listView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/GenericListItem">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> teacherListFragment.java*important code*

```
teacherListAdapter=new TeacherListAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
    teacherListAdapter.setListener(this);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerViewDivider(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(teacherListAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewClickListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerViewClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.d("D", view.getId() + "-" + position);
        }
    }));
```

*getData() returns an List, this code is inside onCreateView*
**TeacherListAdatper**

```
package wan.wanmarcos.views.adapters;

import android.content.Context;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import wan.wanmarcos.R;
import wan.wanmarcos.managers.ItemAdapterListener;
import wan.wanmarcos.managers.ViewHolderSetters;
import wan.wanmarcos.models.Teacher;
import wan.wanmarcos.utils.Constants;
import wan.wanmarcos.views.widgets.CircleTransform;
public class TeacherListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeacherListAdapter.TeacherHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Teacher> teachers= Collections.emptyList();
    private ItemAdapterListener itemAdapterListener;
    public TeacherListAdapter(Context context,List<Teacher> teachers){
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.teachers=teachers;
    }
    @Override
    public TeacherHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(Constants.TEACHER_NEW_ITEM, parent, false);
        TeacherHolder teacherCustomer = new TeacherHolder(view);
        return teacherCustomer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TeacherHolder holder, int position) {
        Teacher teacher=teachers.get(position);
        holder.setElements(teacher);
    }

    public void setListener(ItemAdapterListener listener){
        this.itemAdapterListener =listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return teachers.size();
    }

    public class  TeacherHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ViewHolderSetters<Teacher>,View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView teacherName;
        private RatingBar teacherRating;
        private ImageView teacherImage;
        private TextView teacherCourses;
        private TextView teacherAssumptions;
        private Teacher current;
        public TeacherHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            teacherName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_item_name);
            teacherRating=(RatingBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_item_ratingbar);
            teacherImage=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_item_picture);
            teacherCourses=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_item_courses);
            teacherAssumptions=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_item_faculties);
        }

        @Override
        public void setElements(Teacher elements) {
            current=elements;
            teacherName.setText(elements.getName());
            teacherRating.setRating(elements.getRaiting());
            teacherCourses.setText(itemView.getResources().getString(R.string.teacher_capabilities)+ elements.getFaculties());
            teacherAssumptions.setText(itemView.getResources().getString(R.string.teacher_ped) + elements.getDescription());
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(elements.getImageUrl()).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(teacherImage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //itemAdapterListener.itemClicked(v,current);
        }
    }
}
```

> **WHAT I WANT IS: why child items of my RecyclerVIew are the layouts containers?**
>   I need someone to help me Thanks